# what is difference between string str1 = str ; and string str2((string &)str1);

Tags: c++

I am basically wondering if latter is more efficient/optimized as it is not creating a copy of string ?

i want to make a string using constructor 
like string str(str1,3,5);

Comment: Those three: `string str1 = str;`, `string str2(str);` and `string str3((string&)str);` do exactly the same thing: call copy constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i want to make a string using constructor like string str(str1,3,5);

If we look at the corresponding `std::string` constructor [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), we see that it has signature

```
basic_string( const basic_string& other, 
          size_type pos, 
          size_type count,
          const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Note the `const basic_string& other` part: the string is passed through a const reference, no temporary copies are involved. Thus, `std::string str(str1, 3, 5)` is as efficient as it can be, and doing `std::string str((std::string &)str1, 3, 5)` will only obfuscate the code: it contains a (generally considered bad) C-style cast, it pretends the reference is non-const, and it adds cognitive work for the reader without gaining anything.